# Callhome rest endpoint Device is connected but with unavaliable capabilites #opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I am using Device-Specific Configuration to do the call-home. I am able to discover the call-home device but getting unavailable capabilities. While adding device with schema folder and capabilities runs successfully without unavailable capability.